# Monitor goes black when I open setting in GNOME

Tags: 20.04, gnome, hdmi, monitor, usb-c

I have a Yoga 7i that I have connected to a monitor through USB-C port extension to a monitor that supports HDMI.

When I click on settings in GNOME, the monitor goes black similar to how it would look if it was off. Monitor's power light is still on, so it has power. Ubuntu version 20.04

This will also happen when I install any software through the Ubuntu Software Center. When the installation is over, Ubuntu shows a remove button on the UI. The screen goes blank sometime between those two events and lasts several seconds. It is not a fixed time and duration change. It also happens when I open applications like Videos that open on the monitor connected through HDMI.

I would appreciate any suggestion on how to track the issue.